# Erroneous text layer. Mismatch between kerning in fontforge and in {xe|lua}latex

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontforge

Running `xelatex` (or `lualatex`) on the input

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\(\{f\}\)
\end{document}
```

should produce some form of

> {f}

in the text layer of the PDF. But it produces

> {f }

with a space between f and }. This space shouldn't be there. How to get rid of it?

As for the visible output, here it is:

[image]

As you see, the left brace and f overlap in the PDF.  However, when you open the font with fontforge, and put the left brace with the florin into the metrics window, they don't overlap!  The  output is inconsistent.  What am I missing?  How to increase the kerning properly once and for all for the occurrences of "{*f*" in my huge document (which is not an MWE)? I tried to [improve the font myself](http://anonfile.com/CaF13b37n4/TeXGyreTermesMath-Regular_otf) (the developers didn't react to similar requests in the past), but it lead nowhere so far ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space in the "text layer" of the PDF is inserted by a heuristic of your PDF viewer because there is some distance between the `f` and the `}`. In the long term tagged PDF files should solve that problem, but especially for math formulas I wouldn't hold my breadth. So in the short term, you either specify replacement texts for every math formula using e.g. `repltext` or you live with this space.

Regarding the "inconsistency" in FontForge: The florin sign (U+0192) and the mathematical italic small letter f (U+1D453) are not the same glyph. Comparing both in FontForge shows the same appearance as in TeX:

(Mathematical Italic Small F first, florin second)

[image]

But generally I wouldn't recommend FontForge's metric window for Math output, because Math isn't formatted in the same way as normal text. Especially "classical kerning" like in this case doesn't really exists, because `{` and `f` are separate objects and nor part of a word.

Of course, if you prefer the florin sign over the mathematical f, you can use

```
\Umathcode`\f 7 0 "192
```

after `\begin{document}` such that LaTeX insets the florin sign insteaf of U+1D453 in math mode for a "f". One downside is that the textlayer will contain the florin sign too. You could also modify `U+1D453` directly in FontForge.

Comment: it doesn't look as if tagging would improve the copy&paste with the adobe reader: the heuristic stays and the space is inserted (even in text, e.g. with `\emph{f})`)

Comment: @MdAyq6 I meant that you can modify kerning between { and  U+1D453 (because normal kerning isn't applied AFAIK, but you could modify U+1D453 to be slightly more on the right in general. This would be independent from the left character though, so you would basically e.g. redesign U+1D453 to look more like the florin sign.

Comment: @MdAyq6 If you were using LuaTeX you could always use Lua to add such small changes.

Comment: @MdAyq6 As I read the OpenType MATH specification, they normal kerning be applies. At least not between a operator like `{` and `f`. In practice, LuaTeX would apply kern tables and XeTeX would not, so at least for compatibility I would not use them.

Comment: @MdAyq6 You only kerned u1D453.st and u1D453.sts (the script and subscript versions), not u1D453 itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97632/discussion-between-marcel-kruger-and-mdayq6).